# Transform a polygon into a point on zoom out

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am developing an app using mapbox.
I am using mapbox as **server side data tiles**.
I would like to transform a polygon into a point depending on the zoom level.

Anyone knows if it is possible?

Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various things you could do, depending on what "transform a polygon into a point" means to you:

- Generate both point and polygon versions of the same data, providing them at different zoom levels (server side)
- Generate only polygon versions, but use some trickery to display it as a point (eg, a `symbol` layer or a `circle` layer) at lower zoom levels.
- Generate only polygon versions, but use trickery to generate a GeoJSON `Point` geometry client-side, and display *that* at lower zoom levels.

Depends a bit on your exact purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations, I guess I will pick the 1st solution. Client side is not an option as I have to many objects...